# Programming Logic in Storing Multiple table ids in one table

Tags: data-modeling

I have Five Tables as Below

```
1.tblFruits
2.tblGroceries 
3.tblVegetables
4.tblPlants
5.tblDescriptions
```

All the tables except 5th one `tblDescriptions` will have ids as one column and as primary key and Items as Second Column.

The column in table 1 to table 4 are similar and as follows

```
ids     item_name
```

Now i want to store description of the items of the four table in the fifth table as below

```
Desc_Id   Description     Ids
```

Now the problem is since i am storing the ids to identify the description of the items in the other four table i might get similar ids when i put ids of four table together.

Let me know the table design for the above requirement

Comment: If they're so similar then why are they separate tables?

Comment: I made the question in easy way to understand the logic.My requirement more complex than this.I have more than 25 columns in table 1 to 4 which i said above

Comment: My actual requirement is i am saving page content in different tables and i have to add seo keywords for all the pages stored in different table.Now since the pages are identified by pageIds i want some table structure which store these seo keywords in one single table

Comment: you must tell your case. when you have tables with same structure but different type there's no use in having different table but confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As your tables are similar, the best practice is to combine all of your tables and even description and define row type using a type column.

```
id   name   description   type
                          [Fruits, Groceries, Vegetables, Plants]
```

It's easier to understand and maintain.

But if your tables are different you have two option:

**1- use a super table for your types which produce unique IDs which I suggest.**

2- use a type row in your description field and define it as primary key beside ID in that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
tblDescription
=====================
id | pk_id | description | type

id : auto_generated id of tblDescription
pk_id : foreign key to linked to the tblFruits,tblGroceries.. table
description : the description
type : value either  be fruits, groceries,vegetables,plants .To identify the table.
```

SQL to extract description would be as below:

```
Select f.item_name, d.description from tblDescription d 
inner join tblFruits f on d.pk_id=f.id and d.type='fruits'
inner join tblGroceries g on d.pk_id=g.id and d.type='groceries'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Polymorphic Association`. As foreign key of your 5th table with description use two columns `object_id` and `object_model`.

Example of table content:

```
Desc_Id Description Object_ID Object_Model
1       'dsferer'   12        `Fruit`
2       `desc2      12        `Vegetable`
2       `descfdfd2  19        `Vegetable`
```

Remember to add unique index on both columns for performance reasons.

[Here you](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-and-applying-polymorphism-in-php/) have some article explaining this in PHP